# html input onchange doesn't accept anonymous function

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, input

Why does this not work?

```
 <input type="file" id="kmlFiles2" multiple onchange="function(){alert('why does this not work')}()">
```

chrome gives me an error, 
*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (*.

Firefox tells me *SyntaxError: function statement requires a name*.

But this does work?

```
 <input type="file" id="kmlFiles2" multiple onchange="alert('but this does work')">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ewzyV/

I am asking because I was was trying to use and MVC framework that injects code into the onchange event.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ewzyV/1/

Comment: ^ if you use a function that executes, for instance an IIFE it should work

Comment: ^ but then, what would be the point ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
onchange="(function(){alert('this should work')})()"
```

Comment: only problem is that this way you cant pass in the event... like how do I pass in `onchange="(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); alert('this should work'); })()"`

Comment: err, nm, this seems to work `onchange="(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); alert('this should work'); })(event)"`

Comment: this is the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

Its not a good practice to create inline functions.

I would suggest something like

```
<html>
 <script>
   function myFunction(){
     alert('hey it works');
   }
 </script>
 <body>
 <input type ='file' id='kmlFiles2' onchange="myFunction();" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

you can also consider writing

```
function init(){
   document.getElementById('kmlFiles2').onclick=function(){alert('this also works');};
}
window.onload=init;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                                                            בס''ד
```

With your code segment:

```
    onchange="function(){alert('why does this not work')}()"
```

there is a basic problem.  I would expect from https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp that the format for Javascript is (instead):

```
    object.onchange = function(){myScript};
```

With the onchange evenet, the "object." is implicit already, so the expected correct form to use would be:

```
    onchange= "function(){alert("Why does this not work?"); return;}"
```

The absence of the "return;" statement rarely gives problems but - even so - I include it to make the function complete.

I have a similar situation that I am trying to resolve, so I very much appreciate your bringing up the question.  Thank you and good luck with your programming!

I am starting with this reference:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp

```
    After a function expression has been stored in a variable, the 
    variable can be used as a function:
    Example
    var x = function (a, b) {return a * b};
    var z = x(4, 3);
```

I found that the following code is working:

```
    onchange="{alert('Hello 10'); alert('Hello 20'); return; }"
```

It seems that the "function()" is implicit also.  I tested it and the alert posted two times.  I started out with just the single alert.  Since it works for me, you might want to give this as a hint how it "should" work hopefully for you too.

After testing awhile with the inline functions, they seemed to unstable in order to get something consistently working.  So I ended up with the code below that works solidly for me, simply defining a function to do what needs to be done:

```
<td><strong>Number of Posts For the Carousel to Show:</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 10px;" colspan="2">
<input id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'ceupoststoshow' ) ); ?>" style="vertical-align: middle; horizontal-align: middle;" max="20" min="1" step="1" type="range" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $titleooi ); ?>" onchange="updatetwopoststoshowtext(this.value, this.id, 'ceupoststoshow' , 'titleooi','ceupoststoshowtext')" >
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatetwopoststoshowtext(thistextvalue, thisfieldid, thisoldfromid, thisnewtoidone, thisnewtoidtwo) {
updatepoststoshowtext(thistextvalue, thisfieldid, thisoldfromid , thisnewtoidone);
updatepoststoshowtext(thistextvalue, thisfieldid, thisoldfromid , thisnewtoidtwo);
}
</script>

</td>
<td>
<input style="width: 90%;" type="text" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'ceupoststoshowtext' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'ceupoststoshowtext') ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $titleooi ); ?>" onchange="updatepoststoshowtext(this.value, this.id, 'ceupoststoshowtext' , 'titleooi')" >

<script type="text/javascript">
function updatepoststoshowtext(thistextvalue, thisfieldid, thisoldfromid, thisnewtoid) {
var strthistextvalue= String(thistextvalue); var strthisfieldid = String(thisfieldid); 
var strthisoldfromid=String(thisoldfromid); var strthisnewtoid = String(thisnewtoid);
alert ("UPST hello there! strthistextvalue = " + strthistextvalue + " strthisfieldid = " + strthisfieldid + " strthisoldfromid = " + strthisoldfromid + " strthisnewtoid = " + strthisnewtoid );

var subfieldidlength = strthisfieldid.length - strthisoldfromid.length;
var substrfieldid = strthisfieldid.substring (0, subfieldidlength);
alert ("UPST hello there two! subfieldidlength = " + subfieldidlength + " substrfieldid = " + substrfieldid);

var newstrfieldid = substrfieldid + strthisnewtoid;
alert ("UPST hello there three one! newstrfieldid = " + newstrfieldid);
var newElementId = document.getElementById(newstrfieldid);  
alert ("UPST hello there three two! newElementId.value = " + newElementId.value);
(document.getElementById(newstrfieldid)).value = strthistextvalue;
alert ("UPST hello there three! (document.getElementById(newstrfieldid)).value = " + strthistextvalue);

alert ("document.getElementById (newstrfieldid = " +  newstrfieldid + " ) . value = thistextvalue = " + thistextvalue);
return;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am currently testing what I posted with Firefox 55.0.3 32-bit for 64-bit Windows 10;  I hope to provide an update soon if there are any issues with how they are resolved.

Comment: I love the Besiyata Deshmaya :)

Answer (score 0):

you can't call the anonymous function from html element so you can achieve this by event handling like:

```
<input type="file" id="kmlFiles2" multiple>
 <script>
    document.getElementById("kmlFiles2").addEventListener("change", function(){
        alert('This is working')
    })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use code inside `on***=""` tag

```html
<input type="text" onchange="{ 
     console.log('anything');
}"
```

You can just use {} brackets it be like a export default but you still can use this and events